# How do I set permission for a custom page to be based on node access?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I have added pages using hook_menu like so:

```
function dynamic_entries_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['entries/get'] = array(
            'title' => 'Dynamic Entries',
            'page callback' => 'dynamic_entries_get_entry',
            'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
    return $items;
}
```

A node ID is added to the end of the URL. For example, /entries/get/10. I want to allow access to this page to anyone who has access to the requested node. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `entries/get/%node` as path and [node_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_access/7) as access callback. Also, you might want to consider setting page arguments. It's not a good idea for the page callback to fetch the node id from the URL or using the  [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) function.

```
$items['entries/get/%node'] = array(
  'title' => 'Dynamic Entries',
  'page callback' => 'dynamic_entries_get_entry',
  'page arguments' => array(2),
  'access callback' => 'node_access',
  'access arguments' => array('view', 2),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

BTW the function [node_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_menu/7) is the `hook_menu` implementation of the node module. Looking up how the Drupal core modules implement certain hooks often helps.